# Microcaching with nginx & uwsgi

Tags: nginx, python, cache, uwsgi

i am running my personal website written with python on nginx with uwsgi. Since the site is very static i want to improve the performace by adding microcaching.

Both nginx and also uwsgi do offer caching.

- [nginx microcaching example](https://gist.github.com/fennb/1283573)
- [uswgi caching example](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUwsgiModule)

Can somebody explain the difference between the two variants and give me an advice which one is the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both references you provide are examples of `nginx`'s caching functionality.

They both behave roughly the same but are used for different scenarios:

1. The `proxy_cache` directives are used when the application (generally speaking the *backend*) is accessed through HTTP (i.e. when `nginx` serves as a [reverse] proxy for another web server).
2. The `uwsgi_cache` directives are used when the application is hosted by an instance that uses the `uwsgi` protocol (for example the `uWSGI` application stack).

The directives available for each of the two methods behave very similar if not equally (this - of course - is intended behaviour).
`nginx` also offers similar functionality for e.g. *FastCGI* backends.

Since your setup uses `uwsgi`, you would rather use the corresponding `uwsgi_cache` directives.
Actually, you have to do so unless you want to introduce a second *HTTP*-based (web) server to serve your Python app behind your `nginx` instance.